# Pre-filled 'Add Meta' / Product Options for WooCommerce products when manually adding an order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

We have a store where the most commonly purchased items have a bunch of options that are select at check out (around 10).  These are additional options (think size, color, etc..) that customers select each time they buy these items.

When the customer orders directly, they fill it all out themselves so it's easy.  The problem is, this particular client does around half their business over the phone, and so they enter the orders in themselves in WP-Admin / WooCommerce --> Add Order.

So when they add a product through WooCommerce's Add Order, none of the aforementioned (necessary options) come up to be filled out when the employee is manually entering that person's information in (doing through the front end is not an option either).

They are currently using the 'Add Meta' option next to the product, and manually typing in the option categories every single time themselves.  E.g. Add the product, and then Add Meta --> Color, Add Meta --> Size, etc.. (ten times).

This is obviously time adds to the time it takes, so in an ideal situation would like to have the same options for the product being added on the customer facing website, to also appear when adding the products manually in the backend.

Comment: Easiest way is using some POS plugins like https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-pos/.

Comment: Sounds like a programming job to me. Ask a freelancer if he implements the missing options.

Comment: If it is about meta tags, You can use plugins like ACF to create a meta box so that you don't have to go through the Add Meta process every time.

Comment: What are the meta keys for `additional options` and default values for them ?

Comment: It's quite simple.  When you checkout for a T shirt on the front end, there are options for size, length, width, color etc..   I just need those options to appear in the back end too when manually adding in an order.